# How to determine the location of the insertion point in a UITextField

Tags: ios5, uitextfield

I have a UITextField subclass.

Ultimately, I'm trying to determine which word in the text field's content is under the insertion point.

My specific question is whether I can query a UITextField for the current insertion point.

`UITextFieldDidChangeNotification` fires whenever I move the insertion point within the field, so *something* is being tracked. But I can't find anything to query in the text field instance to tell me where the insertion point is now located.

Being able to ask for a character offset from the beginning of the visible text would be swell.

Is this possible in iOS 5?  I've looked through other related Q&A here and the consensus seems to be that it wasn't possible in iOS 4 or earlier.

I've diddled around with the `UITextInput` protocol and managed to get some data that looks relevant:

```
UITextRange *selectedTextRange = [super selectedTextRange];
UITextPosition *start = [selectedTextRange start];
UITextPosition *end = [selectedTextRange end];
NSLog (@"selectionRange: %@; start: %@; end: %@", 
        selectedTextRange, start, end);
```

Is there a way to turn a UITextPosition into a relevant NSRange or some kind of character offset to let me know where the insertion point is?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: And here it is:     NSInteger offsetOfInsertionPoint = [super offsetFromPosition:[super beginningOfDocument] toPosition:[[super selectedTextRange] start]];